# Printing parts of a string from a variable that can change

Tags: python, string, variables, indexing, slice

I'm trying to figure out what is probably something very simple. I need to make a program where I print the user's specified city and state that they provide. They need to type it in as city,state in the input statement and their answer is stored in a variable called `userInput`.

Now, here's my issue: Users won't always have the same city and state. Thus, the index numbers of the string that they need to give will change. My question is: How do I print these two things apart from one another, no matter their position in the string?

Edit: Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
userInput = input("Enter your city and state in the format city,state ")
```

The program should print "You live in the state of [state the user types]" on one line and "Your city is [city the user types>]" on the other.

Comment: This would be a little easier to understand if you provided a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

If user always input "city,state" with a comma separator you could use `split()`

```
user_input = input("Enter city,state  :")
city, state = user_input.split(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `str.split()` function to split the user's input at the comma, and use formatted strings to print the values into the lines:

```
city, state = input("Enter your city and state in the format city,state ").split(',')

print(f"You live in the state of {state}\nYour city is {city}")
```